# list and explode

Tags: php, list, arrays, url-rewriting, explode

I am trying to use url rewriting on my website and I want to use the `list()` and `explode()` functions to get the right content.
Currently my code looks like this:

```
list($dir, $act) = explode('/',$url);
```

In this case `$url` is equal to everything after the first slash in the absolute url i.e. `http://example.com/random/stuff => $url = random/stuff/` this would work fine, but if I want to go to `http://example.com/random/` then it will print a notice on the page.  How do I stop the notice from showing up do I need to use something other than the `list()` function?

Right now the notice is "Notice: Undefined offset: 1..."

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Fixes for this issue aside, you should turn off the display of PHP errors on your production site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should check how many path segments the URL contains:

```
$segments = explode('/', $url);
if (count($segments) !== 2) {
    // error
} else {
    list($dir, $act) = $segments;
}
```

But maybe you should choose a more flexible approach than using `list`.

Comment: What would be an example of a more flexible approach?

Comment: @TheGNUGuy: That depends on your requirements, how your application expect to receive its arguments.

Comment: I adapted your solution above to use a switch statement so more easily deal with multiple different cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Try this :

```
list($dir, $act) = array_pad(explode('/',$url), 2, '');
```

`array_pad` complete the array with your values, here is : `''`.

Comment: `list($a, $b, $c) = explode('/', $url) + ['x', 'y', 'z'];` to have different _defaults_.

Comment: The solution of @Tom looks also pretty nice. My suggestion with single default values

`list($a, $b, $c) = explode('/', $url . '//');`

Answer (score 4):

Check out [`parse_url`](http://ca.php.net/parse_url)

Comment: This link-only answer is low-value.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to split your line of code in several, to ensure you never assign non-existing values to variables -- which is what you are doing when `explode` only returns one portion of URL.

For that, not using `list` seems like the right solution, as, with list, you must know how many elements the expression on the right of `=` will return...

And, in this situation, **you don't know how many elements `explode` will return**.

For instance, something like this might be OK :

```
$parts = explode('/', $url);
if (isset($parts[0])) {
  $dir = $parts[0];
  if (isset($parts[1])) {
    $act = $parts[1];
  }
}
```

Of course, up to you to deal with the situation in which `$dir` and/or `$act` are not set, later in your script.

Another solution would be to check how many elements explode will return *(counting a number of `/` for instance)* ; but you'll still have to deal with at least two cases.

Answer (score 1):

to get rid of the notice:

```
list($dir, $act) = explode('/',$url);
```

but maybe a better solution would be:

```
$segments = explode ('/', $url);
$dir = array_shift ($segments);
$act = array_shift ($segments);
```

if there is no 2nd segment, $act would be null and you can also more than 2 segment this way

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to suppress the E_NOTICE on list assignment as of PHP 5.4+ is the following:

```
@list($dir, $act) = explode('/', $url);
```

If `$url` contains no `/`, explode will return one element and `$act` will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exploding the full URL, try `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, assuming '/random' names the script.

Comment: Downvoter: what's wrong with PATH_INFO? The question is ambiguous enough to allow for this possibility.

Answer (score -1):

The simple and ugly answer is to prefix the whole thing with a single '@' which suppresses error outputs. $act will be set to null in that case because under the hood, it's equivalent to:

```
$foo = explode('/',$url);
$dir = $foo[0];
$act = $foo[1]; // This is where the notice comes from
```